# How to insert an URL link into an image

Tags: python, image, url, dll, python-3.7

I'm trying to create an image and insert a link into it with Python 3.7

I couldn't find anything working here, I just have:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from PIL import Image


url = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.google.com/')

img = Image.open(urlopen('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png'))
img
```

Comment: what do you mean by "insert a link into it"?

Comment: like to embed it, I want to click the image and go to the url site

Comment: You want  to embed the image in what? A pdf? a word document? a webpage?

Comment: It does not work that way, you can't have a png or wtv format with a link. When you press an image and you go to a website is because the website where the image is redirects you.

Comment: Is not possible then? I want the output to be an image where I click and then go to the link. I've been seen solutions but for previous Python versions..